# Some external hard drives not recognised by mac

Tags: time-machine, external-disk

Running High Sierra.
I used a Seagate external hard drive and a Verbatim hard drive for Time Machine backup. Suddenly they are both not recognised by the iMac. 
The power lights are on and the disks are spinning.
I have tried direct connection and via a usb hub.
I have tried different cables.
I have another Seagate hard drive which works fine in both the hub and direct connection and with all the cables.
How do I wake up the 2 drives?
Disk Utility does not recognise them either.

Comment: Please post the output of `diskutil list` (Terminal command) with your disks attached.

Comment: you might download the App Mountain from the Mac App Store and see if it will recognize and mount the drives. i've had very good luck this app.

Comment: Did the trouble occur after you upgraded from Sierra to High Sierra?

Comment: You don’t mention how old they are - could they both have failed? Or were they disconnected during a read/write operation? - trashing them?

Comment: Not sure how old they are; I'd say both about 5 years.

Comment: It's possible they were disconnected while being used. Just don't know.

Comment: CasJen-iMac:Desktop CasJen$ diskutil list
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         1.5 TB     disk3s2

CasJen-iMac:Desktop CasJen$

Comment: Had to delete info on 2 internal disks to fit data in. Both external drives were connected with power lights on.

Comment: Did you try connecting the disks to another computer? Possibly another OS like Linux or Windows? Try if the disk is recognised in some other computer.